# Android: Protecting paid app from piracy?

Tags: android, google-play

I read about questions similar to what I am about to ask, but the answers are old and not very useful. So I will ask the question hoping that android has a certain system nowadays that protect paid apps.

If I created an app and then published it as a paid app on google play store, and keeping in mind that there seems to be multiple ways for users to download paid apps for free. Then what is the benefit for the developer from that.

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to protect my paid app against piracy?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way and it is called Google Play [License Verification Library (LVL)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/).

This lets you call Google's servers and check the user has bought the app. For this to work effectively you should verify this value server side.